# how to select one record from multi records of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables,
Table 1:

```
ID    Name
1     Adam
2     Bob
```

...

Table 2:

```
ID    Visit
1     2019-01-01
2     2019-01-02
1     2019-01-03
1     2019-01-04
2     2019-01-04
1     2019-01-05
```

...

I would like to get the most recent visit from table 2 for each name in Table 1, such as

```
Name    LastVisit
Adam    2019-01-05
Bob     2019-01-04
```

I tried join them together using

```
select tbl1.name as "Name", MAX(tbl2.visit) as LastVisit
from table1 tbl1 join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id;
```

but it is not working, how should I do this?

Comment: Create an inline view for table 2, which has ID with Max visit date and use that to join with table 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `group by`:

```
select t1.name, MAX(t2.visit) as LastVisit
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.name;
```

Comment: will "group by" guarantee to select the max date?

Comment: @dguan . . . `group by` creates a result set with one row per `name`.  Each row has the maximum value of the date, due to the `max()` function.